# javascript - How to map a backend entity to a frontend entity (and the opposite)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I need to do a mapping between 2 javascript entities:

- The entity that comes to me from a backend service (backend layer)*(*1)*
- The entity that is used in an html form (frontend)

*(*1)The backend entity comes from a Java REST service.*

Unfortunately, **the entity that comes to me from my backend service has a structure that is not manageable from my form, so I need to use different frontend entity that can be easy to manipulate in the view's logic**.
This mapping has to serve in both directions, that is:

- **frontend -> backend**
- **backend -> frontend**

This html form handles a fairly large entity, with many fields and sections (variable and objects), so it is not a trivial mapping.

As a simple example:
Supose I receive this entity from the backend:
**Entity 1**

```
{
    "a": "aValue",
    "b": "aValue",
    "c": "aValue",
    "d": {
        "da": "aValue",
        "db": "aValue",
        "dc": "aValue",
    }
}
```

And I need to convent it this way
**Entity 2**

```
{
    "x1": {
        "a": "aValue",
        "b": "aValue"
    },
    "x2": {
        "c": "aValue"
    },
    "x3": {
        "da": "aValue",
        "db": "aValue",
        "dc": "aValue"
    }
}
```

The mapping between these two jsons is given by the property names.
For example: the "a" property in the first json is mapped to "x1.a" on the second json.

So my question is:
**Is there a good practice to achieve this in javascript?**

**EDIT:** 
To make more clear what I'm looking for, what I need is something like this (but nicer, and not a pain in the ass to mantain when the entities are large):

```
function mapBackToFront(backendEntity) {
    var myNewFrontEntity = {
            x1: {
                a: backendEntity.a,
                b: backendEntity.b
            },
            x2: {
                c: backendEntity.c
            },
            x3: {
                da: backendEntity.da,
                db: backendEntity.db,
                dc: backendEntity.dc
            }
        }
    };

    return myNewFrontEntity;
}

function mapFrontToBackEntity(frontEntity) {
    var myNewBackEntity = 
    {
        "a": frontEntity.x1.a,
        "b": frontEntity.x1.b,
        "c": frontEntity.x2.c,
        "d": {
            "da": frontEntity.x3.da,
            "db": frontEntity.x3.db,
            "dc": frontEntity.x3.dc,
        }
    };

    return myNewBackEntity
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what's the pattern to generate the desired output?

Comment: Hi. As an example I put two jsons in my post. That would be the pattern.
I need to convert those two json to eachother. The mapping is given by the properties names

Comment: @Ele I updated my question. In the EDIT part I clarify wath i'm looking for. Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, someone on the way gave me this answer. A mapping based on rules where each rule declares the mapping between each property of the entities.

Here is the code:

```
const rules = [
    ["a","x1.a"], 
    ["b","x1.b"],
    ["c","x2.c"],
    ["d.da","x3.da"],
    ["d.db","x3.db"],
    ["d.dc","x3.dc"]
];
function put(entity, s, v) {
    let path = s.split('.');
  let key = path.pop();
  let o = path.reduce( (current, b) => {
    if (!current.hasOwnProperty(b)) {
        current[b] = {};
    }
    return current[b];
  }, entity);
  o[key] = v;
  return entity;
}

function get(entity, s) {
  return s.split('.').reduce( (current, b) => {
    return current[b];
  }, entity);
}

const entity1 = {
    "a": "aValue",
    "b": "aValue",
    "c": "aValue",
    "d": {
        "da": "aValue",
        "db": "aValue",
        "dc": "aValue",
    }
};
const entity2 = {}
```

It's preety much what i was looking for. I tested it and the mapping works in both ways, from entity1 to entity2 and from entity2 to entity1.

Here is all the code: https://jsfiddle.net/L39wn3ap/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can convert that json from backend on **backend**.

You'll need to use **.map()** function from js , if you want to convert on frontend.

And **foreach()** or **for()** , if you want to convert on backend.

Please , provide a **fiddle** , so i can help you with that.

P.S. What language is used on backend?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Im not sure if we are talking about the same.
Do you mean Array.prototype.map()?
My backend comes from a Java REST service. Can't modify it.

Comment: @aee  , Yes. I mean Array.prototype.map().

Comment: "You can convert that json from backend on backend." - cant do that.
So, using map I can translate both json in my example?
https://codepen.io/aee/pen/XqpNVZ
Please give me an example of doing that

Answer (score 0):

the `$http` service provides you the option to transform requests and responses from server, as described in the  [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#transforming-requests-and-responses).

What you should do is to override the default transformer with you own function by doing:

```
$http({
  url: '...',
  method: 'GET',
  transformResponse: myCustomTransformer
})
```

and your custom transformer should look something like:

```
function myCustomTransformer (responseData) {

    var clientObj = {
        // build your client side object based on the response object from the server
    };

    return clientObj;
};
```

There is a possibility to invoke your custom transformer after the default one, by adding your transformer to the array of transformers `$http.defaults.transformResponse` (all explained in the docs above)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunetly that doesn't resolve my problem. Your answer says WHEN I could do the mapping and what I'm looking for is HOW I could do the mapping in an acceptable way.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify what I want to achieve